# What is difference between JRE and JVM ? How does an applet works if there is no JDK present in a system?

Tags: java, applet

How does an applet works if there is no JDK present in a system . I mean if we have to download JDK to compile or run our java modules then how these java applets works in our system through web browser?? 
And what about mobiles and other gadgets they dont have JDK as well. 
And who generates the Byte Code and How it is complied by JRE? 
Thanks in Advance !! :)

Comment: jdk = java DEVELOPMENT kit. jre = java RUNTIME ENVIRONMENT...

Comment: JDK (Java *Development* Kit) is used to *develop* Java programs. JRE (Java *Runtime* Environment) is used to *run* Java programs. Browsers, mobile devices, and other gadgets are able to run Java programs because they'll have a *JRE*.

Comment: if they already have JRE And our systems already have JRE why do we have to download it??

Comment: Read my question once again and if you still can't see the difference . Don't answer it. :) I am askin why do we have to download it if it is already in our systems and if it is not then how does applets work. without JRE??

Comment: Applets use the JRE to run applets and most all windows and Linux computers come with the JRE pre-installed on them. If you try to run an applet without Java they won't run at all.